# Need to change alpha of imageView in colapsinglayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have toolbar, tab layout and imageview inside Collapsing layout. I need to change alpha of that image to be equal of collapse state of that imageview. It means ->

image completely hide : alpha = 0%

image 50% scrolled : alpha = 50%

image completely shown : alpha = 100%

Unfurtunatelly, i haven't found any xml parameter which could affect this. Is there any simple solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try a couple of things depending on your needs.

If you're looking for a simple solution you may be able to use the `app:contentScrim` XML attribute on `CollapsingToolbarLayout` to achieve the effect you're looking for. See: [Coordinator Behavior ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36000261/coordinator-behavior-imageview?rq=1)

If that isn't sufficient, a more "correct" solution would involve adding an `OnOffsetChangedListener` and using that to calculate and apply the alpha change for your `ImageView`. See: [android setAlpha on imageView into CollapsingToolbarLayout does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37898089/android-setalpha-on-imageview-into-collapsingtoolbarlayout-does-not-work)

Comment: Thank you. The second solution was exactly what I need. It works great.

Answer (score 3):

Also if you have some layouts you could use scroll listener like this:

```
appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener((appBarLayout, verticalOffset) -> {
            float offsetAlpha = (appBarLayout.getY() / appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange());
            int value = 255 - (int)(255 * offsetAlpha * -1);
            toolbarTotalContainer.getBackground().setAlpha(value);
        });
```

Where `toolbarTotalContainer` is some container of some Views.